# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project jenkins: There are test failures

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am getting this error during maven test:

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.633 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-15T12:49:31+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project jenkins: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\ramiz\mavenDemo\jenkins\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\ramiz\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7616380274041274645\surefirebooter2203282479078194733.jar C:\Users\ramiz\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7616380274041274645 2020-01-15T12-49-30_729-jvmRun1 surefire8024714674651187567tmp surefire_01357391895941968741tmp"
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\ramiz\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7616380274041274645\surefirebooter2203282479078194733.jar C:\Users\ramiz\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire7616380274041274645 2020-01-15T12-49-30_729-jvmRun1 surefire8024714674651187567tmp surefire_01357391895941968741tmp"
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml looks like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ramiz.train</groupId>
  <artifactId>jenkins</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <!--  
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>  
  -->

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Surefire-reports log shows this:-

## Created at 2020-01-15T12:49:31.348

Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. Stream 'The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified.'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream stdin corrupted. Expected comma after third character in command 'The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified.'.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient$OperationalData.(ForkClient.java:511)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.processLine(ForkClient.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.consumeLine(ForkClient.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer$Pumper.run(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

The Java , maven versions i am using

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-25T01:19:05+05:30)<br/>
Maven home: C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.3<br/>
Java version: 1.8.0_241, vendor: Oracle Corporation<br/>
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre<br/>
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252<br/>
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"<br/>
```

I am not sure whats happening here. Please help.
I have tried all the solutions available. but no success.

Comment: Maybe a memory issue? I would try to increase the memory available to the JVM forked by the Maven Surefire plugin, sort of
`<argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>`

Comment: tried using <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine> it did not work.

Comment: Issue reported on 8u241, have you observe the same issue on earlier versions as well?

Comment: You could try a completely different JVM, like one from adoptopenjdk.net. I like openj9, small memory footprint.

Comment: The error rather suggests that either a plugin or your application writes to stdout. Have you looked into that? Also, you could try to run it on Linux just to make sure.

Comment: @Fairoz i have tried on 1.7, 11 and 13 as well but same error.

Comment: @Ben i will try these.